# When I render this It became a small dot

Tags: rendering

When I render this It became a small dot. Can anyone tell me how can I solve this?

[image]

Here is the Blend file:
https://gofile.io/?c=ZdoCEr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render visibillity for the array modifier was turned off.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ieatdrugsforbreakfast